# 3-step Latent Profile Analysis in R?

Tags: r, multinomial, mclust

I was wondering if it is possible to run a **3-step Latent Profile analysis in R**.

This would involve treating latent profiles as categorical variables, then running multinomial logistic regression models to identify the likelihood (with the Odds Ratio in comparison to a reference profile) of profile membership.  These would also be adjusted for misclassification of profile membership.

MPlus 7.3 can run this analysis, but as far as I can tell, this cannot be achieved in R.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might be a better fir for [stats SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you! I have posted there.